# Can you open a JPEG, add text, and resave as a JPEG in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-manipulation

I want to write a small program in .NET 4.0 that will open a .jpg (or .jpeg) file, add a line of text to the image, and then resave the image as a .jpg.  Does anyone know the easiest way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Keep in mind, resaving a JPEG (especially one you've modified) compresses it again, and each compression tosses out some detail.  When you do this, if you must, do it as few times as possible.

Comment: @cHao - another option would be to generate/output the image on the fly while maintaining the original without a watermark.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var filePath = @"D:\Pictures\Backgrounds\abc.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = null;

// Create from a stream so we don't keep a lock on the file.
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
}

using (bitmap)
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
using (var font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Regular))
{
    // Do what you want using the Graphics object here.
    graphics.DrawString("Hello World!", font, Brushes.Red, 0, 0);

    // Important part!
    bitmap.Save(filePath);
}
```

Comment: can you do this without saving?

Comment: @DB Yup, you can use the [`Bitmap.Save(Stream, ImageFormat)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) overload to write to a stream (e.g. a `MemoryStream`).

Answer (score 3):

```
var myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\myImage.jpg");
var g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
g.DrawString("My\nText", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.White, new PointF(0, 0));
```